# How to update many databases when we update any table?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am creating a C# Windows application which is based on a medical inventory.In this application I have mainly three forms as PurchaseDetail,SalesDetail,and StockDetail.

Now I want a functionality in which if I insert or modify the records in PurchaseDetail,or SalesDetail, the data in the StockDetail should also be modified.(for example if i insert some quantity of medicines in PurchaseDetail then Quantity in StockDetail should also modified and same as for SalesDetail )

**Columns in PurchaseDetail:**
Id(Primary Key and auto increment int),BatchNumber,MedicineName,ManufacturingDate,ExpiryDate,Rate,MRP,Tax,Discount,Quantity

**Columns in SalesDetail:**
Id(PrimaryKey and auto increment int),BillNumber,CustomerName,BatchNumber,Quantity,Rate,SalesDate

**Columns in StockDetail:**
Id(Primary Key and auto increment int),ProductId,ProductName,OpeningStock,ClosingStock,PurchaseQty,DispenseQty,PurchaseReturn,DispenseReturn

Please help me.

Comment: You mean update many **tables** instead of **databases** ?

Comment: So at what point do "many databases" get involved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are talking about 3 tables in one database (although the title seems to indicate otherwise).

You could use [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to achieve what you are asking for. (Note that I gave you a tsql example in the link)

OR,

You could write a transactional procedure to perform all steps (or none) at once.

Comment: I would note that putting your business logic in a trigger can result in becoming a little bit lost.  If it's in your code, then it's obvious for any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean 'update many tables', not multiple databases.

There are at least 3 ways to do this

1. Database Triggers on PurchaseDetail and SalesDetail which also update StockDetail.
2. Wrap the inserts into PurchaseDetail or SalesDetail with Stored Procs, which also update the StockDetail accordingly
3. Do this from code (in your C# layer), similar to 2.